# Assigning New Value to string inside an IF is not being applied

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm currently doing a work project and I'm currently using a string to identify if this is the first time a button is clicked and when it is clicked it would change a value against a string that says "Yes" to "No"

I have tried using both number and strings but it seems the changes are not applying.

```bsh
$UserFirst = "Yes"

$UsernameColumn          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$UsernameColumn.text     = "Username"
$UsernameColumn.width    = 100
$UsernameColumn.height   = 50
$UsernameColumn.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,60)
$UsernameColumn.Font     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$UsernameColumn.Visible  = $true
$UsernameColumn.Add_Click({
    if ($UserFirst -eq "Yes") {
        $UserFirst = "No"
        $FullQueryString.Text += "First"
    } else {
        $FullQueryString.Text += "Second"
    }
})
```

I expect the result of "First,Second,Second,Second,Second" with 5 button presses but I'm getting "First,First,First,First,First".

Comment: $UserFirst = "Yes" is at the very top of the code, not sure if that is what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: `$UserFirst = "No"` -> `$script:UserFirst = "No"`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that has worked.